# Blogger Items page Custom setting

Tags: xml, html, blogger

I want to customize my blogger template,
I have removed everything from the template. I have designed some of the part, but got stuck in a problem.

I could not assign Post body only for blog Posts. I have tried to put
`<data:post.body/>`
but it doesn't show any output.

Please provide some solution to problem. I want to show post body only on item page.

You can see the site, i am working on [click to proceed](http://paparesults.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Please have look at this help article, which says [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It could massively help if you show the involved code instead of posting just a link to a website.

Comment: Thank you sir, i am new at stack overflow. I will learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render the post body, you will need to have the `Blog` widget on the page -

```
<b:section id='page-body' preferred='yes'>
  <b:widget id='Blog1'
            title='Blog Posts'
            type='Blog' />
</b:section>
```

Once you have saved the theme, refresh the page. You will notice that the `Blog` widget has been auto-populated with the default configuration. You can now go ahead and remove everything that you don't require (so that only `<data:post.body/>` remains)